Cannot implement routing in react "dispatcher is null"
App.js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header  from  './componentes/Header';
import FormularioLogin from './componentes/FormularioLogin';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from './pages/Menu';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: 'menu', Component: <Menu /> },
  { path: '/', Component: <App /> },
])

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;

Menu.js
export default function Menu() {
  return (
    <div>teste</div>
  )
}

The app as created with create-react-app
Complete error

Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
dispatcher is null
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35452:7
RouterProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31433:66
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56085:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60056:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61359:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46341:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46385:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46442:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66340:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65588:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65511:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65484:11
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64879:78
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72919:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72897:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73134:25
ERROR
dispatcher is null
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35452:7
RouterProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31433:66
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56085:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60056:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61359:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46341:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46385:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46442:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66340:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65588:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65511:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65484:11
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64879:78
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72919:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72897:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73134:25
ERROR
dispatcher is null
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35452:7
RouterProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31433:66
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56085:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60056:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61359:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46341:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46385:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46442:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66340:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65588:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65511:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65484:11
recoverFromConcurrentError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64976:38
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64889:26
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72919:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72897:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73134:25
ERROR
dispatcher is null
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35452:7
RouterProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31433:66
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56085:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60056:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61359:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46341:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46385:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46442:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66340:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65588:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65511:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65484:11
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64879:78
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72919:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72897:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73134:25
ERROR
dispatcher is null
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35452:7
RouterProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31433:66
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56085:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60056:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61359:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46341:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46385:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46442:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66340:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65588:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65511:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65484:11
recoverFromConcurrentError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64976:38
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64889:26
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72919:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72897:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73134:25
ERROR
dispatcher is null
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35452:7
RouterProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31433:66
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56085:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60056:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61359:20
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66318:18
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65588:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65511:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65484:11
recoverFromConcurrentError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64976:38
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64889:26
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72919:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72897:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73134:25



This is error appears when I edit the component. When first starting the development server a blank page appears. But navigation doesn't work, a blank page appears for all routes. "/", and "menu".

I made some changes and it worked, I don't know, It seems it was related to the imports.

Issue
The App component is recursively rendering itself.
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: 'menu', Component: <Menu /> },
  { path: '/', Component: <App /> }, // <-- rendered by App!
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;

Don't do this since there is no base case to end the recursion, App never gets a complete JSX value to render returned to it. You have effectively created a form of infinite render-looping.
Solution
Remove the root "/" route rendering App, or render anything else other than App.
Examples:
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: 'menu', Component: <Menu /> },
  // RRD will complain about no "/" route though
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: 'menu', Component: <Menu /> },
  { path: '/', Component: <Home /> },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;


It seems like there's an issue with how you're implementing routing in your React application. The error message "dispatcher is null" suggests that there might be a problem with the way you're setting up your router.
The code you've provided seems to be attempting to use createBrowserRouter from react-router-dom, but it's not being used in the correct way. Here's how you can fix it:

Import BrowserRouter: First, import BrowserRouter from react-router-dom instead of createBrowserRouter.

Wrap Your App Component with BrowserRouter: Wrap your App component inside BrowserRouter in your index.js file, which is typically the entry point of your React application.


Here's how you can update your code:
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

And in your App.js, you don't need to create a router manually. You can just return the components you want to render:
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import FormularioLogin from './components/FormularioLogin';
import Menu from './pages/Menu';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/menu" component={Menu} />
        <Route path="/" component={FormularioLogin} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Make sure you have the correct imports for BrowserRouter, Route, and Switch from 'react-router-dom'.
This setup should resolve the "dispatcher is null" error and correctly implement routing in your React application.

Is this a Gen-AI answer? It's not correct and the suggestion is for a previous version of React-Router-DOM that OP isn't using.
